# Formatting column in pandas to decimal places using table.style based on value

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I am trying to format a column in a dataframe using style.
So far I successfully used the styling for a fixed number of decimals:

mytable.style.format('{:,.2f}', pd.IndexSlice[:, ['Price']])

but I need to expand this to formatting based on value as this:

- if value is >=1000, then format to zero decimal places
- if value is between 1000 and 1, then format to two decimal places
- if value is < 1, then format to five decimal places

Does anyone have a solution for this?
Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Building upon @Code_beginner's answer – the callable should return formatted string as output:

```
def my_format(val):
    if val >= 1000:
        return f"{val:,.0f}"
    if val >= 1:
        return f"{val:,.2f}"
    return f"{val:,.5f}"

mytable.style.format({'Price': my_format})
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is called "conditional formatting". In which you set the conditions like you described and return the right format. There are examples in the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.format.html), they used a lambda function there. But you can also create a normal function which might look something like this:

```
def customfunc(val):
    if val>=1000:
        format='{:,.0f}'
    if val<1000 and val>=1:
        format='{:,.2f}'
    if val<1:
        format='{:,.5f}'
    return format

df.style.format({0:customfunc})
```

This should style your first column like described in your problem. If the columns has a name you have to adjust it accordingly. If you have trouble see the documentation linked abve there are more examples.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! It seems to pick up the correct formatting for each value but the display on the whole column looks like this:{:,.5f} {:,.2f} etc... so instead of values I get only this. Any ideas why?

Comment: I've posted a new message with a screenshot of current situation.

Answer (score 0):

Just to have it visually clear, this is how it looks now:
[image]

That's my line of code:

```
df.style.format({'Price': customfunc})
```