# Style.format column in dataframe to absolute values

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have the following problem. I have a column in a dataframe (let's call it df['Price']) and I need to format in to two decimal places, but for negative values I need the minus sign gone, since I already have a coloring formatting which colors me in red the negative values.

```
df.style.format({'Price': '{:,.2f}'})
```

This is the generic formatting which works fine, but how do I change this to solve my problem? I basically need to send the absolute values of the column to formatting instead the actual values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [pandas documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.format.html) you can pass a callable as formatter. Therefore you can just take the absolute value.

```
df.style.format({'Price': lambda x: f"{abs(x):,.2f}"})
```

Comment: By any chance do you see any problem with the solution on this topic: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70884452/formatting-column-in-pandas-to-decimal-places-using-table-style-based-on-value/70885550#70885550. Because I couldn't make it work even though the solution seems legit. I am using the styler as part of a streamlit dataframe display.

Answer (score 2):

You can pass a callable to `.format` as well – see https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/style.html#Formatting-Values.

This should do the trick:

```
df.style.format({'Price': lambda value: f'{abs(value):,.2f}'})
```

Comment: Thanks! By any chance do you see any problem with the solution on this topic: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70884452/formatting-column-in-pandas-to-decimal-places-using-table-style-based-on-value/70885550#70885550 Because I couldn't make it work even though the solution seems legit.